# wordpress post title with only number return 404 error

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I am using wordpress with Permalink Custom Structure /%category%/%postname%/

When I create a post with "numbers only" post title, the page return 404 at the browser. But with "letters only" post title, there is no issue.

For example:

https://xxxxxxxxxx.com/category/3333/  return 404 error

Any idea why? thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

- Maybe in your theme there is no archive page so create taxonomy single archive page(archive.php).
- in case your theme is not single-postType page to create single-postType page and update your permalink  and recheck
- update your permalink and again check this link

Comment: thank you, my theme has archive.php and single.php, any thought?